# ionic async ngFor data

Tags: asynchronous, ionic-framework, storage

> UPDATE ON BOTTOM

I am trying to show data in an *ngFor that i'm getting from an object that is getting retrieved asynchronously from ionic storage. At the moment i am getting a blank screen.

I have tried multiple things like using async pipes in different manners.
Does anybody know the right way?

Here is my storage service method that is getting called:

```
public getFlow(flowId:number){
       return this.storage.get(FLOWS_KEY).then((flows:Map<number,Flow>)=>{
           return flows.get(flowId);
       });
    }
this returns a Promise<Flow>
```

this is my component code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Flow } from '../../model/Flow';
import { FlowService } from '../../model/services/flowService';
import {CreateTaskPage} from '../create-task/create-task'
import { Task } from '../../model/Task';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-flow',
  templateUrl: 'flow.html',
})
export class FlowPage {
  flow;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private flowService:FlowService,public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
    this.flow = this.flowService.getFlow(Number(this.navParams.get("flowId")))
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad FlowPage');

  }

  createTask(){
    const modal = this.modalCtrl.create(CreateTaskPage,{flowId:this.flow.flowId});
    modal.present();
  }
  swipe(e,task:Task){
    if(e.direction == 2){
      console.log("panUp");
      task.column--;
    }
    if(e.direction == 4){
      console.log("panDown");
      task.column++;
    }
  }
}
```

My html:

```
<ion-content padding>
<div *ngIf="(flow | async)">
 <div *ngFor="let col of flow.columns;index as i">
    <h2>{{col}}</h2>
   <div *ngFor="let task of flow.getTasksFromCol(i)">
      <ion-card (swipe)="swipe($event,task)">
          <ion-item>
              <h2>{{task}}</h2>
            <button ion-button item-end clear icon-end> 
                <ion-icon name='more'></ion-icon>
              </button>
            <p>{{task}}</p>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-card>
   </div>
</div>
</div>

<ion-fab right bottom>
  <button ion-fab color="light"><ion-icon name="arrow-dropleft"></ion-icon></button>
  <ion-fab-list side="left">
    <button (click)="createTask()" ion-fab><ion-icon name="add-circle"></ion-icon></button>
    <button ion-fab><ion-icon name="create"></ion-icon></button>
  </ion-fab-list>
</ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

Thanks for helping.

UPDATE:

I found one big mistake in my component it now looks like this:

```
  flow:Flow;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private flowService:FlowService,public modalCtrl: ModalController) {
    this.flowService.getFlow(Number(this.navParams.get("flowId"))).then(flow =>{
      this.flow = flow;
    })
  }
```

i also updated my html but it still isn't working: i now get error:

> ERROR TypeError: _co.flow.getTasksFromCol is not a function
>       at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

This is weird because this method exists in my Flow Model:

```
import { Task } from "./Task";

export class Flow {
    //PK for 1-n relation with task
    flowId:number;
    projectName:string;
    columns:string[];
    tasks: Map<number,Task>;

   constructor(flowId:number,projectName:string,columns:string[],tasks:Map<number,Task>){
    this.flowId = flowId;
    this.projectName = projectName;
    this.columns = columns;
    this.tasks = tasks;
   }

   public getTasks(){
    return Array.from(this.tasks.values())
}
    public getTasksFromCol(colNumber:number){
        var tasks = new Array<Task>();
        for(let task of Array.from(this.tasks.values())){
            if(task.column == colNumber){
                tasks.push(task)
            }
        }
        return tasks;
    }
}
```

> UPDATE2
>   i now added this to my service

```
public getTasksFromCol(flowId:number,colNumber:number){
        return this.storage.get(FLOWS_KEY).then((flows:Map<number,Flow>)=>{
           var flow:Flow = flows.get(flowId);
           var tasks = new Array<Task>();
           for(let task of Array.from(flow.tasks.values())){
               if(task.column == colNumber){
                   tasks.push(task)
               }
           }
           return tasks;
        });

    }
```

do i just call this in my html page? i'm kinda stuck

Answer (score 1):

I found your mistake.

You have created one variable.

```
flow:Flow;
```

You have assigned value to that variable.

```
this.flow = flow;
```

Now you need to understand that variable has contains some value related to what you have assigned. So you can't access **flow.getTasksFromCol()**

Thats the reason you have faced this error.

ERROR TypeError: _co.flow.getTasksFromCol is not a function at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

**Solution:-**

Just move this getTasksFromCol() method to service and apply html like following,

I hope it's working. Let try this once and let me know if any error.

Comment: How would you implement this? let the service retrieve the flow and then get the wanted tasks?

Comment: Now my storage doesn't seem to be working anymore, the db got deleted and if i create a flow it doens't go to the DB. Something very strange is happening lol

Comment: i added the method to my service. i tried calling it in my html but my app then just freezes.